# redirect all www non-www to https non-www

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website example.com, I want to redirect the following urls -

```
www.example.com
example.com
https://www.example.com
```

to https://example.com

what I have tried so far is  this -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This gas worked well except for https://www.example.com

Help is appreciated!!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` are not right for your requirements.

You can have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

OR to use `www.example.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: the above answer for www to non www doesn't work, the below one does.

Comment: Glad it worked. First rule is for `www` removal and 2nd rule is for adding `www` in the domain name.